# beautifulsoup to get tags with style "display:none"

Tags: selenium, beautifulsoup, webdriver, styles

I am building a crawler of web pages and encountered a page with the following undisplayed tag.

```
<div style="display:none; padding:3px 10px 5px;text-align:center;" id="dialogCookieInfo" title="taiwan high-speed rail" wicket:message="title=bookingdialog_3">
        <div class="JCon">
            <div class="TCon">
                <div class="overDiffText">
                    <div style="text-align: left;">
                        <span> for better user experiences, bla bla <a target="_blank" class="c" style="color:#FF9900;" href="https://www.thsrc.com.tw/tw/Article/ArticleContent/d1fa3bcb-a016-47e2-88c6-7b7cbed00ed5?tabIndex=1">privacy protection</a>。</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="action">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input hidefocus="" name="confirm" id="btn-confirm" type="button" class="button_main" value="我同意"/>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As usual, this tag is to be displayed in the rendering and actually in front of all other tags. 
It actually shadowed all the other tags for a confirmation or cancel answer. 
The problem is that beautifulsoup does not return this tag in my program's query properly.
Beautifulsoup just said that this tag was of style "display:none" and did not reveal the tag's other attributes and its children. 
But I need this tag to check if it is the one that shadowed all other tags.
Can anyone help me answering the following questions ?

1. how do I get those tags with style "display:none" ?
2. Is there a better way to get those tags that dynamically shadow all other tags after rendering ?
3. If this tag shadowed all other tags and I queried whether the other tags were enabled or not, what responses will webdriver give ?

Really appreciate all the responses.

Comment: I was thinking maybe it is due to a bug of beautifulsoup.  But when I reimplemented the code with LXML, I found that LXML still skipped the tag.  Can anyone help by telling me what my bug is ?  Or it is just due to the style of "display:none" ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is exactly want you need, but hopefully it at he very least gets you going in the right direction. But, you can iterate through the `<div>` tags and check if it has a "style" attribute. If it has a "style" attribute, then you can check if there is "display:none". When these are true, you can do whatever it is you need to do with those tags.

```
html = '''<div style="display:none; padding:3px 10px 5px;text-align:center;" id="dialogCookieInfo" title="taiwan high-speed rail" wicket:message="title=bookingdialog_3">
        <div class="JCon">
            <div class="TCon">
                <div class="overDiffText">
                    <div style="text-align: left;">
                        <span> for better user experiences, bla bla <a target="_blank" class="c" style="color:#FF9900;" href="https://www.thsrc.com.tw/tw/Article/ArticleContent/d1fa3bcb-a016-47e2-88c6-7b7cbed00ed5?tabIndex=1">privacy protection</a>。</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="action">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input hidefocus="" name="confirm" id="btn-confirm" type="button" class="button_main" value="我同意"/>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>'''



import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

div_display = soup.find_all('div')
for ele in div_display:
    try:
        ele['style']

        if 'display:none' in ele['style']:
            print ('Found "diplay:none"')
            # Do some stuff with this element
        else:
            print ('Did not find "diplay:none"')
    except:
        print ('Element did not have "style" attribute')
```

**Output:**

```
Found "diplay:none"
Element did not have "style" attribute
Element did not have "style" attribute
Element did not have "style" attribute
Did not find "diplay:none"
Element did not have "style" attribute
```

Comment: Thank you very muich. 
The problem is that beautifulsoup in fact did return the tag but with one attribute style="display:none".
All the other attributes are not seen and the child tags are also skipped. 
I guess I could then use find the tag in the html source file.
But I was thinking maybe beautifulsoup can do that in some way for me.

Comment: Note I had to use `if 'display: none'` with a space. Whether the HTML contains `display:none` or `display: none`, BeautifulSoup returns it with the space for me

Comment: You’re using this html?