# I am trying to find a way to determine the visibility of an HTML element in Python without using the Selenium WebDriver. How to do this using Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, dom

I am trying to find a way to determine the visibility of an HTML element in Python without using the Selenium WebDriver. I know that the `.is_displayed()` method in the Selenium webdriver can be used for this purpose, but for some reason, my project is not able to use Selenium. I have been unable to find an alternative solution to this problem and any help would be greatly appreciated.

To be more specific, I am looking for a way to check the visibility of an HTML element in Python without using Selenium or any other web driver. Is there a way to do this using Python alone, or perhaps with the help of a different library? If so, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or examples of how to implement this.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54866270/2681662

Comment: for eg. this website - https://jobs.dell.com/form/candidate/699974/375/19744418 has lot of input elements that are hidden. I am building a generic code for any website that can check and extract only those elements that are visible. @MSH